# ARIMA Model (2,1,0)

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive

Could someone show me how to express this model mathematically?

I'm not sure I quite understand how to write it out because I feel like I'm seeing a lot of different notations in different books.

Comment: Try looking up existing questions. There quite a few similar examples already.

Comment: @RichardHardy I came across that but the addition of the seasonal term made me pretty unsure which parts corresponded to which.

Comment: Have you checked the other similar threads? I would be surprised if none of them were close enough.